# Php search bar can't display results

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

```
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] != ""){
        $safe_value = $_POST['search'];
        $safe_value = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$safe_value);
        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM quote WHERE quoteID LIKE '%$safe_value%' OR quotations LIKE '%$safe_value%' OR author LIKE '%$safe_value%' OR genre LIKE '%$safe_value%'");


        if($count == 0){
            echo "No Results Found";
        }else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $quotations = $row['quotations'];
                $author = $row['author'];
                $genre = $row['genre'];

            echo " <p> ";
            echo " Quote Number : $quoteID <br> ";
            echo " Author : $author <br>";
            echo " Quotations : $quotations <br>";
            echo " Genre : $genre <br>";
            echo "<hr> </p>";
            }
        }
    }

<form method="post" action="search.php">
 <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
 <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="submit">
 <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
</form>
```

> My database consists of this;
>
> QuoteID | Quotations    | Author        | Genre |
>
> 1. | "some quotes" | "Some author" | "Some genre" |
> 2. | .... and so on..

I plan to search from my search bar, and it would display all the information from the database.

It shows that the database is connected, yet it doesn't display the results. What am I missing?

//Attached a link here for my webpage with the problem (Top orange icon for the search bar)

Visit http://khcy4dau.mercury.nottingham.edu.my/Assignment%20/

Comment: dump your query, and check, is that gives back the desired result in mysql directly.

Comment: Try this `$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM quote WHERE quoteID LIKE '%$safe_value%' OR quotations LIKE '%$safe_value%' OR author LIKE '%$safe_value%' OR genre LIKE '%$safe_value%'") or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl I have tried the method you described, and it still says "Result Not Found"

Comment: @lolka_bolka I have check the statement on the database using SQL and its able to retrieve the data, yet it can't be done on the php

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). What you have here is extremely reckless, your `safe_value` method is pure voodoo.